# Horizontal Bar Chart in Xamarin for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, bar-chart

I am creating some bar charts in iOS app in Xamarin.
Currently I am using the "Bar Chart" Component by Xamarin.
I have checked all possible methods to make as horizontal bar chart but cannot see anything.
My question is, how can i set the bar chart orientation to horizontal?
Or if it is not possible, can you please recommend some free Xamarin Component for horizontal bar chart.
I also tried using "Alliance Charts" Component in Xamarin and I don't know also how to make it in horizontal view.
In case that there is none, we might check other options for rendering the data in a chart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a horizontal bar chart demo by [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) for Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android here:

https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-stacked-bar-chart-example/

[image]

This is achieved by having a normal stacked bar chart, and rotating the chart by setting XAxis.AxisAlignment = AxisAlignment.Left and YAxis.AxisAlignment = AxisAlignment.Top

Full source code for the example is available at the link above.

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the scichart xamarin project*